# Encontrar o índice de todas as ocorrências numa string com jquery

Tags: jquery, string, índices

Como encontrar o índice de todas as ocorrências de uma uma string dentro de uma outra string com jquery?

Exemplo: String toda "três tigres tristes para três pratos de trigo, três pratos de trigo para três tigres tristes."

String que quero encontrar os índices : "três"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Pode utilizar uma regex combinada com um while para isso:

```
var re = /três/g,
    idx = [],
    str = "três tigres...";

while ((match = re.exec(str)) != null) {
    idx.push(match.index);
}
```

Segue o [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/buh159/yoeszhea/1/).

---

Uma outra alternativa sem a regex, seria implementa sob o prototype da própria String. O código fica bem mais extenso:

```
(function() {
  String.prototype.allIndexOf = function(string, ignoreCase) {
    if (this === null) {
      return [-1];
    }
    var t = (ignoreCase) ? this.toLowerCase() : this,
      s = (ignoreCase) ? string.toString().toLowerCase() : string.toString(),
      i = this.indexOf(s),
      len = this.length,
      n,
      indx = 0,
      result = [];
    if (len === 0 || i === -1) {
      return [i];
    }
    for (n = 0; n <= len; n++) {
      i = t.indexOf(s, indx);
      if (i !== -1) {
        indx = i + 1;
        result.push(i);
      } else {
        return result;
      }
    }
    return result;
  }
})();
```

Uso:

```
suaString.allIndexOf("três");
```

Segue o [**fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/buh159/yoeszhea/).

Obs: As alternativas acima são sem o jQuery hehe'

Comment: Opa, valeu mesmo! Ajudou bastante :D